# On the divisibility of $(x+y)^k - 1$ by $xy$

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a fixed $k \geq 2$, are there infinitely many *non-trivial* coprime integer pairs $(x,y)$ for which $xy$ divides $(x+y)^k-1$? By *trivial* I mean parametrized pairs $(x,y)$ of the form $(-1,-1),(x,1),(1,y),(x,1-x),(x,1 - x^n),(1-y^n,y),(x,p(x)),(p(y),y)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial factor of $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$. When $k$ is even there are a few more trivial pairs, namely $(x,-1),(-1,y),(x,-1-x),(x,x^n-1),(y^n-1,y)$; where $n>0$ is a multiple of $k$.

Comment: What about $x+y=1$?

Comment: You might as well ask when $xy$ divides $x^{k}+y^{k}-1.$

Comment: Good point, I'll add that too.

Comment: You mean like $x=3,y=5,k=4$? There are tons of other examples. Have you computed anything?

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, I know that it's the same thing, why do you think it's better?

Comment: Simpler is usually better.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch, I guess I need to reformulate my question: for a fixed k exceeding 2, aside from the obvious cases, is there an infinitude of solutions?

Comment: Put another you: you will have a solution if and only if you have both $y^{k} \equiv 1$ (mod $x$) and $x^{k} \equiv 1$ (mod $y$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: That's cool which might run through the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "obvious cases". That is, list all the cases that you think are obvious so that we know what the question is, really.

Comment: @GH from MO, done.

Comment: I think the example given by Felipe Voloch is not in your "obvious" list.

Comment: @GH from MO, because it is not obvious.

Comment: Any pair of coprime integers $x,y$ with ${\rm lcm}(\phi(x),\phi(y)) = k$ will do.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, that's it, you are right! And I bet that there is some simple way to convert a single non-trivial solution satisfying your criterion into an infinitude of other solutions.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson But, for fixed $k$, there are only finitely many $x$ with $\phi(x) \leq k$. So this can't give infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson and also $\phi(x)$ is even for $x > 2$, so this construction covers only even $k$.

Comment: One reason we can not expect infinite (parametrized) solutions out of something like $\phi$ is: the solutions $(x,y)$ lack $xy<0$ in this case. I believe infinitude would not be possible (for fixed $k)$ if $x, y>0$ is a limitation unless $(x,1)$ or $(1,y)$.

Comment: @David Speyer: Yes, I understand that, of course, I just thought it was worth pointing out that there are such solutions, which might count as "non-trivial" ( and of which the already noted $x = 3, y =5, k = 4$ is a special case).

Comment: @David Speyer: I guess one could sharpen the condition and say that  a necessary and sufficient condition is that ${\rm lcm}({\rm ord}_{x}(y),{\rm ord}_{y}(x))$ divides $k$, where ${\rm ord}_{a}(b)$ denotes the multiplicative order of $a + b\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ for coprime integers $a$ and $b.$ It's not clear though that that provides any insight into whether there is an infinitude of "non-trivial" solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research online I found out that there's a lot of theory behind this subject and it was studied by several authors (see the references below).

As it was pointed out by @Geoff Robinson, the question essentially reduces to finding all coprime integer pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \mid 1-y^k$ and $y \mid 1-x^k$.

It turns out that the solutions have a recursive pattern, and this phenomenon was observed by @Aaron Meyerowitz in one of the answers given above. From a single solution one can produce an infinitude of solutions, which form a so-called *1 chain*. A 1 chain is a recursive sequence $u_n = (1-u_{n-1}^k)/u_{n-2}$, with non-zero $u_0, u_1$ being given (note that this definition of a 1 chain differs from [4]).

The following construction is a slight variation of Mohanty's argument [4]:

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are coprime integers which satisfy $x \mid 1-y^k$ and $y \mid 1-x^k$. Then there exists a unique $r \in \mathbb Z$ such that $xr=1-y^k$. But then

$$xr \equiv 1 \pmod{y},$$

$$(xr)^k \equiv 1 \pmod{y},$$

and since $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod{y}$ we have

$$(xr)^k-x^k\equiv 1 - 1 \pmod{y},$$

which results in $x^k(r^k - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{y}$. Since $\gcd(x,y)=1$, we conclude that $y \mid r^k - 1$. Since $r \mid y^k - 1$, we conclude that $(y,r)$ is also a solution. By proceeding in the same fashion we can generate an infinitude of solutions (see [4] for more details).

Mohanty himself studied a slightly different problem, namely he looked for coprime solutions $(x,y)$ such that $x \mid y^3+1$ and $y \mid x^3 + 1$. One can see that $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a solution, and the sequence $u_0=1, u_1=1, u_n=(u_{n-1}^3+1)/u_{n-2}$ looks as follows:

$$1,1,2,9,365,5403014, \ldots$$

This is a sequence [A003818](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C9%2C365&sort=&language=&go=Search) in OEIS. According to Benoit Cloitre, this sequence "is asymptotic to $\exp(F_{2n}\cdot \log c)$ where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci's number and $c\approx1.1137$".

In 1], Bier studies the *polynomial system of congruences* of the form $x \mid g(y)$ and $y \mid f(x)$, where $f(t), g(t) \in \mathbb Z[t]$. He fully classifies for which pairs $(\deg f, \deg g)$ it is possible to have only finitely many solutions. It turns out that there are only finitely many such pairs, and the pairs $(k,k)$ for $k \geq 2$ are not among them.

Any suggestions on how to obtain an asymptotic formula $A(M)$ for the number of solutions satisfying $\max(|x|,|y|)\leq M$ would be greatly appreciated.

References:

1] T. Bier, *Finite or infinite number of solutions of polynomial congruences in two positive integer variables*, Springer Proceedings in Mathematics & Statistics, pp. 11 - 26, 2014.

[2] J. Brzeziński, W. Holsztyński, P. Kurlberg, *On the congruence $ax+by\equiv 1$ modulo $xy$*, Experimental Mathematics 14 (4), pp. 391-401, 2005.

[3] E. Dofs, *Solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3=nxyz$*, Acta Arithmetica 73 (3), pp. 201 - 213, 1995.

[4] S. P. Mohanty, *A system of cubic Diophantine equations*, Journal of Number Theory 9, pp. 153 - 159, 1977.

[5] L. J. Mordell, *The congruence $ax^3+by^3+c\equiv 0 \pmod{xy}$, and integer solutions of cubic equations in three variables*, Acta Mathematica 88, pp. 77 - 83, 1952.

Comment: The system $x \mid y^2+1$ and $y \mid x^2+1$ has infinitely many solutions. There is the unique $1$-chain $2,5,13,34,\cdots$ of alternate Fibonacci numbers. Here $u_n = (1+u_{n-1}^2)/u_{n-2}.$ Note that this provides an infinite chain of solutions to  $x \mid y^{4}-1$ and $y \mid x^{4}-1$ and hence to  $x \mid y^{4j}-1$ and $y \mid x^{4j}-1$ for any fixed $j.$ Likewise the mentioned solutions to  $x \mid y^3+1$ and $y \mid x^3+1$ provide solutions to $x \mid y^{6j}-1$ and $y \mid x^{6j}-1.$

Comment: It is not hard to use Maple to generate all the solutions to $x \mid y^k-1$ and $y \mid \x^k-1$ up to $x \lt y \lt N$ fairly quickly (say for $N=3000$ and $k \le 6$) Just factor $x^k-1$ and check the divisors $y \gt x$ to see if also $ x \mid y^k-1.$ This gives the start of several chains $v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots$ for which $(x,y)=(v_i,v_{i+1})$ are solutions and from that conjectures can be made.

Comment: @Aaron Meyerowitz thanks a lot for your comments, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 8):

For fixed $k$ and $y=\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$ we have $$x^k \equiv 1 \pmod y$$and $$y \equiv 1 \pmod x$$ so also $$y^k\equiv 1 \pmod x.$$

That isn't one of your trivial examples, but maybe it should be.

Actually, $y$ could be any polynomial factor of $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}.$ For example,

$\frac{x^{30}-1}{x-1}=\Phi_3\Phi_5\Phi_{15}\Phi_{30}=$

$ (x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^8-x^7+x^5-x^4+x^3-x+1)$$(x^8+x^7-x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2+1)$

So for $k=30$ one has $x,y$ where $y$ is any of the $16$ products of the factors.

Maybe you want a parametric family that is not $y=p(x).$

**Interesting Variant** To have $xy$ divide $(x+y)^2+1$ is quite interesting. I saw it in a movie (in another form). It may have been a math olympiad problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You are right, I should add this example to the list of trivial examples (despite its non-triviality).

Comment: If $(x+y)^2+1=kxy$, then $k=5$, this is indeed known

Comment: Also the pairs $x,y$ that make this true are known.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov could you please provide a reference to this result?

Comment: @Anton for example https://brilliant.org/wiki/vieta-root-jumping/

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y)$ is an integer solution, then $((1-y^k)/x,y)$ also is, iterating this produces many series of solutions starting from 'trivial'.

Answer (score 2):

Another family of answers which I don't think is of the other forms: For $k=3$, consider $x=t^2$, $y=1-t^3$. More generally, if $(t^j)^k-1$ has a factor of the form $\phi(t) = 1 + \sum_{m \geq j} c_m t^m$, even if $\phi(t)$ is not of the form $f(t^j)$, then $(t^j, \phi(t))$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Felipe gave the "sporadic" example $x=3,y=5$ for $k=4.$ Other solutions for $k=4$ are $(x,y)=(2,3),(3,5),(5,8),(8,13),(13,21)\cdots$ and also $(x,y)=(2,5),(3,8),(5,13),(8,21),\cdots$

All these pairs have $x^2 \equiv \pm1 \pmod y$ and $y^2 \equiv \pm1 \pmod x$ which is of course related. 
The pairs $(3,8),(8,21),(21,55),\cdots$ are the ones with $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod y$ and $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod x$

I suggest computing to see what else turns up. I wouldn't be surprised to see other Fibonacci related families.